# No read permission ot token returned by client credentials grant type

Tags: cloud-foundry, cloudfoundry-uaa

In my apps, I don't want to store personal username and paawordk. So, I  use the client_id and client_secret to get a token, grant type use client credentials. See following:

```
curl --request POST --url 'https://<url>/oauth/token' --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data grant_type=client_credentials --data 'client_id=my client id' --data client_secret=my client secret 
{"access_token":"eyJhbGci****************","token_type":"bearer","expires_in":43199,"scope":"uaa.none","jti":"226cd7d96f354e9c97ebaa3a25f30c40"}
```

The scopes corresponding to the token are uaa.none. Neither cloud_controller.read nor `cloud_controller.write` includes in that. So, I can't read the events, applications and so on.

How can I get the access token with `cloud_controller.read` scope?

Comment: How did you create the client, `my client id` from your example? What `uaac` command did you run? With a client credentials grant, you would set the `authorities` of your client to contain the scopes you require, like `cloud_controller.read`.